# Malformed HTTP Queries

Tags: php, http, query-string

I had an interview question a while back where I was asked to write my own version of PHP's `http_build_query` function, which accepts a hash of keys and values to encode as parameters in a web request. (The original function also accepts objects, but for the purposes of the interview, I only needed to accept hashes.)

I wrote a recursive function that could handle an infinite number of nested hashes, but was told that I was missing several edge cases. One such edge case, which I did figure out, was encoding special character, but in the end I didn't get all of the edge cases and my interviewer never told me what I was missing.

My question is this: What are the edge cases one must look out for when encoding HTTP parameters? (I am well aware that many languages/frameworks have something that do this for you, but that is NOT what I am asking for.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this-- this is one of the edge cases that I did find. For the purposes of the interview, we said "let's just assume I've given you a function that takes a string and encodes all of the special characters in the string so that it is safe". However, the interviewer seemed to suggest there were more edge cases I was missing. Since I usually work in Ruby on Rails, and most of these things are done for me, I never bothered to think about this kind of thing.